# How to Draw chart in windows phone 8 or 8.1 without using external library?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, drawing, windows-phone-8.1

How can I can draw a simple chart in `Windows Phone 8 or 8.1` without using an external library, I want to use **C# + XAML** code only.

I searched for a free library to do that on `Windows Phone 8.1` (universal app) but I couldn't find any. All libraries I've found supported `Windows Phone 8` or 7, not `Windows Phone 8.1`.

Comment: One way I've done this in the past is just turn a custom styled read-only slider or progress bar on its side to make it vertical and then just set the min/max values accordingly so I could actively move chart bars with other controls.

Comment: Pretty slick Chris heheeh, but what if you have a lot of data points?

Comment: What Chart? Basically you can do lots of things using Lines, Ellipses and Rectangles. Create a UserControl and data bind a list to it. Inside the list you have to calculate the positions/heights/widths of the elements, based on the available height/width and recalculate this values on Arrangement/SizeChange event handlers. It's mostly about math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made in answer in this similar question [How to do Chart on Windows Phone Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155021/how-to-do-chart-on-windows-phone-universal-app/26106136#26106136)

It might be able to help you. Telerik has an API that costs money and Google have a free one where you can get Charts through http requests. Check my reply - you might wanna use one of these. My answer is not about drawing it through XAML / C# which can be quite comprehensive.

To Draw it yourself through code you probably wanna create a Custom Control. Here is a few links to get you started:

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WPF-Line-Graph-Basics-033dd90e
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291567.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using the default tools is very hard, you can use [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx) controls, though